# What is the meaning of double circles and double squares in EER-modeling?

Tags: entity-relationship

I´m trying to understand some EER-models and I can't figure out what the difference between a normal circle/square/diamon and a double circle/square/diamond is.

What is the original writer trying to tell me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, a double circle means: multi-valued attribute

A double-rectangle means: weak-entity class

Answer (score 1):

And double diamond is related to the weak entity(double rectangle). 2 weak relationships (or 2 double diamonds) can branch from the same weak entity. Weak diamonds must have weak entity/s.